# Android GCM - not getting registration token

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I am implementing GCM. I have registered my application on Google developer Console, enabled the GCM API services, place google-services.json in app folder, put following in manifest :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="<my-package-name>.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

<application>..
<meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        <!-- GCM  -->
        <receiver
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmReceiver"
            android:exported="true"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
                <action android:name="android.net.conn." />

                <category android:name="<my-pakage-name>" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

<service
            android:name=".notifications.GCMListenerService"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

        <service
            android:name=".notifications.InstanceIDListenerService"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

        <service
            android:name=".notifications.RegistrationIntentService"
            android:exported="false"></service>
</application>
```

## App level build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.1.0'
}
```

## project level build.gradle

```
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:1.4.0-beta3'
    }
```

Therefore my query is, I don't know what is wrong with above that I amot getting registration token. Please help me to get registration token

Comment: What you see in logs?

Comment: Nothing related to GCM..

Comment: Have you added correct sender id while registration?

Comment: @Dhaval where to put sender ID while registration?

Comment: `InstanceID instanceID = InstanceID.getInstance(this);
String token = instanceID.getToken("SENDER_ID", GoogleCloudMessaging.INSTANCE_ID_SCOPE, null);` Add you sender id in `getToken` call. You will find this code snippet in `RegistrationIntentService` class.

Comment: I think InstanceID automatically gets detected from google-services.json file.

Comment: May be you can try adding manually and see if it work?

Answer (score 1):

You need to create your own Receiver and Service and use it like this.

**Receiver:**

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v4.content.WakefulBroadcastReceiver;


public class GCMMessageReciever extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        ComponentName comp = new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(),
                GCMIntentService.class.getName());
        startWakefulService(context, (intent.setComponent(comp)));
        setResultCode(Activity.RESULT_OK);

    }
}
```

**Service:**

```
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.SharedPreferences.Editor;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager;

import com.appdupe.uberforxserviceprovider.R;
import com.google.android.gcm.GCMBaseIntentService;
import com.uber.driver.MyMainFragmentActivity;
import com.uber.driver.constants.Constants;
import com.uber.driver.gcm.ServerUtilities;
import com.uber.driver.util.Utils;

public class GCMIntentService extends GCMBaseIntentService {

    private NotificationManager mNotificationManager;

    public GCMIntentService() {
        super(Constants.SENDER_ID);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRegistered(Context context, String registrationId) {
        Intent i = new Intent(Constants.PUSHNOTIFICATION);
        i.putExtra(Constants.DB_PHONE_GCM_ID, registrationId);
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).sendBroadcast(i);
        ServerUtilities.register(context, "name", "email", registrationId);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMessage(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String jsonString = intent.getExtras().getString("message");

        try {
            SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager
                    .getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
            Editor editor = preferences.edit();

            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonString);
            if (jsonObject.getString("id").equals("1")) {
                editor.putFloat(Constants.USER_LATTITUDE,
                        Float.parseFloat(jsonObject.getString("lattitude")));
                editor.putFloat(Constants.USER_LOGITUDE,
                        Float.parseFloat(jsonObject.getString("logitude")));
                editor.putString(Constants.USER_RANDOM_ID,
                        jsonObject.getString("random_id"));
                editor.putBoolean(Constants.IS_USER_SET, true);
                editor.putString(Constants.PHONE_CLIENT,
                        jsonObject.getString("client_contact"));
                editor.putString(Constants.PHONE_OPEARTOR,
                        jsonObject.getString("operator_contact"));
                // editor.putBoolean(Constants.IS_USER_SET, true);
                editor.putString(Constants.CLIENT_NAME,
                        jsonObject.getString("client_name"));
                sendNotification(jsonString);
            } else {
                editor.putBoolean(Constants.DB_IS_JOB_DONE, true);
                editor.putInt(Constants.FRAGMENT_POSITION,
                        Constants.FRAGMENT_MAP);
                editor.putString(Constants.USER_RANDOM_ID, "");
            }
            editor.commit();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Utils.log("Received message.. " + jsonString);
        Intent i = new Intent(Constants.PUSHNOTIFICATION);
        i.putExtra("json", jsonString);
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).sendBroadcast(i);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDeletedMessages(Context context, int total) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(Context context, String errorId) {
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean onRecoverableError(Context context, String errorId) {
        return super.onRecoverableError(context, errorId);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onUnregistered(Context arg0, String arg1) {

    }

    private void sendNotification(String msg) {

        mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) this
                .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
                new Intent(this, MyMainFragmentActivity.class),
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
                this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                .setContentTitle(
                        getResources().getString(R.string.text_uber_driver))
                .setStyle(
                        new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
                                .bigText(getResources().getString(
                                        R.string.text_job_assigned)))
                .setDefaults(
                        Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND
                                | Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE);

        mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
        mBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);

        Notification notification = mBuilder.build();
        notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
        mNotificationManager
                .notify(Constants.NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());
    }
}
```

**Android manifest:**

```
<application>..
<meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        <!-- GCM  -->
        <receiver
            android:name=".GCMMessageReciever"
            android:exported="true"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
                <action android:name="android.net.conn." />

                <category android:name="<my-pakage-name>" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

<service
            android:name=".GCMIntentService"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

        <service
            android:name=".notifications.InstanceIDListenerService"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

        <service
            android:name=".notifications.RegistrationIntentService"
            android:exported="false"></service>
</application>
```